# How can I use Geo::Coder::US and Geo::TigerLine to convert U.S. street addresses to geospatial coordinates?

Tags: perl, geolocation, geocoding, geospatial, cpan

I'm working from [Geo::Coder::US](http://p3rl.org/Geo%3a%3aCoder%3a%3aUS) and [Geo::Coder::US::Import](http://p3rl.org/Geo%3a%3aCoder%3a%3aUS%3a%3aImport). They say I need to import the database, their examples do not show how to do it, at least for a way that works now. Geo::Coder::US wants to see a Berkeley DB. Geo::Coder::US::Import has sample code to create the database that doesn't work. The code:

```
Geo::Coder::US::Import->load_tiger_data( "TGR06075" );
```

crashes, saying:

> can't read TGR06075.RTC: No such file or directory at ./import.pl line 7

Is the string out of date? Could someone provide sample code which will populate the database so Geo::Coder::US has everything it wants?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files you are looking for are probably located here:
    ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2011/

Answer (score 3):

I found [this](http://www.census.gov/geo/www/tiger/) in the CPAN Docs of [Geo::Coder::US::Import](http://search.cpan.org/~sderle/Geo-Coder-US-1.00/US/Import.pm#SEE_ALSO). You might be able to use the examples given in the docs with the new version of these files. It looks like you are supposed to get the files yourself anyway. They do not seem to come with the module.

Thus, it makes sense that it can't find the database file.

I sneaked a look at [Import.pm](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/SDERLE/Geo-Coder-US-1.00/US/Import.pm):

```
sub load_tiger_data {
    my ($class, $source) = @_;

    my $DB = \%Geo::Coder::US::DB;
    croak "No database specified" unless tied( %$DB );

    open TIGER, "<$source.RTC" or croak "can't read $source.RTC: $!";
    Geo::TigerLine::Record::C->parse_file( \*TIGER, \&_type_C );

    open TIGER, "<$source.RT1" or croak "can't read $source.RT1: $!";
    Geo::TigerLine::Record::1->parse_file( \*TIGER, \&_type_1 );
```

Looks like it appends `.RTC` to the argument, making it a file name. Therefore, I recommend to try to find current data at the Census web site, place it somewhere near your working directory and then try again with the data's file name.